# What are the different ways to copy and back up devices?

Tags: dd, copy, clonezilla

The `dd` command is one method to copy files from one device to other device. Other method is using Clonezilla. What are other ways to do it. What are the differences? In what conditions it's preferable to use this and not that?

Comment: Clonezilla is not to copy files, but *clone* disks and partitions.

Comment: Using `rsync` is a common way to do backup, it supports full backup and backing up only changed files. Also using `tar` or `cpio` to pack and transport backupfiles via network to backup server. Also `find` can find all or changed (newer than) files and precess them.

Comment: You have a large number of questions centered around backup. There's nothing wrong with this, but if you're looking for an answer to a problem you have, it may be better to describe your problem in as much detail as possible, and ask for advice and solutions.

Comment: @vidarlo: Yes, because I had problems with different situations. One situation was copying a smaller USB drive into a larger one and then to distributing the remaining free space into two partitions.